# How to avoid perl -pe from printing unmatched lines

Tags: regex, perl

The following will print out "chicken", which is expected:

```
echo "I like chicken" | perl -pe 's|.*(chicken).*|\1|'

Output: chicken
```

However, the following will print out "I like bacon" even if "chicken" was not matched:

```
echo "I like bacon" | perl -pe 's|.*(chicken).*|\1|'

Output: I like bacon
```

How can I avoid the unmatched string from being printed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s///` is for substitute, which I don't think is what you want to do.  `s|.*(chicken).*|\1|` tells perl to find a line with 'chicken' in it, and replace the word 'chicken' with itself.

Instead use `m//` for regex matching, and use `-ne` instead of `-pe`:

```
echo "I like chicken" | perl -ne 'print if m|chicken|'
```

Output: `I like chicken`

```
echo "I like bacon" | perl -ne 'print if m|chicken|'
```

*no output*

Comment: Thank you, that helps. However I want to print "chicken" in the first example which is the value between parentheses, not the whole phrase. Is this possible?

Comment: I got it: echo "I like chicken" | perl -ne 'print $1 if m|.*(chicken).*|'  
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NaderChehab Since you're not using anchors, there's no need for `.*` in your regex: `perl -ne 'print $1 if m|(chicken)|'`